# Is there a timer function that doesn't depend on a key press

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a timer in my program and i've tried using time.time() but my time taken value is depended on when I completely terminate the program, not when the final output occurs. So, if i don't terminate the program and wait, the time is longer than if i just immediately end the program. Is there an alternative or am i just using it wrong?

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time

t0 = time.time()

(code block)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
t1 = time.perf_counter()
total = print(t1-t0)
```

Comment: Please show how you are using it and your code. Also highlight what exactly in your code you wish to time

Comment: You need to explain this better. Or give a code example. :)

Comment: have you tried using `time.time()` either side of the section you wish to time and then subtracting one from the other using `timedelta`?

Comment: People write video games in Python that rely on the fine-grained control of event times, so yes it is possible, doubtless in more than one way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Notebook` you can put `%%time` at the beginning of any cell to measure the time for the whole cell or `%time` for only the next line.